# How can I create an instance of controls in a designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a bunch of HTMLGenericControls in a  designer file and a c# method which populates the body of them. I am trying to create an ajax call to this method but I cannot access any of the controls from a static context. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: post what you have tried so far

Comment: Nothing! 

I'm going to try creating a method for each control returning the data and then adding the data to control body through the ajax success call. As long as I can set the body through jquery i think im sorted

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to [The name gridview1 does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257016/the-name-gridview1-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/41275212#41275212)

If the controls aren't automatically generated into the .designer file, add class-level variables yourself to the .aspx.cs (in your case, variables of type HTMLGenericControl)